# Major performance problems on our production SQL Server, how would I troubleshoot this?

Tags: sql-server, performance, vmware, cpu

This question is basically the a follow up question to this question:
[Strange performance problem with SQL Server 2016](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186597/strange-performance-problem-with-sql-server-2016/186602?noredirect=1#comment363857_186602)

We now went productive with this system. Though another application database was added to this SQL Server since my last post.

these are the system stats:

- 128 GB RAM (110GB Max memory for SQL Server)
- 4 Cores @2.6 GHz
- 10 GBit network connection
- All the storage is SSD based
- Program files, Log files, database files and tempdb are on separate
  partitions of the server
- Windows Server 2012 R2
- VMware Version HPE-ESXi-6.0.0-Update3-iso-600.9.7.0.17
- VMware Tools version 10.0.9, build 3917699
- Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64)   Oct 28 2016 18:17:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

[image]

Our system now has major performance issues. Very High CPU usage and thread counts:
[image]

Wait stats of activity monitor (I know it is not very reliable)

[image]

Results of sp_blitzfirst:

[image]

Results of sp_configure:

[image]

Advanced server settings (unfortunalty only in german)

[image]

MAXDOP Setting was changed by me.

**I'm aware that this propably isn't a issue with the SQL Server itself**. Its propably an issue with either virtualization (vmware), network related (I already tested this) or the application itself. I just want to nail it down even further.

Would high ASYNC_NETWORK_IO result in a high thread count for the sqlserver process? I'd imagine it spwan many workers because threads can't be closed. Is that right?

I will provide any additional info you need. Thanks in advance for your support!

**EDIT:**

Result of `sp_Blitz @OutputType = ‘markdown’, @CheckServerInfo = 1`

**Priority 1: Backup**:

- Backing Up to Same Drive Where Databases Reside  - 5 backups done on drive E:\ in the last two weeks, where database files also live. This represents a serious risk if that array fails.

**Priority 1: Reliability**:

- Last good DBCC CHECKDB over 2 weeks old

  - babtec_prod - Last successful CHECKDB: 2017-08-20 00:01:01.513
  - D3PR - Last successful CHECKDB:  never.
  - DEMO77 - Last successful CHECKDB: 2016-02-23 20:31:38.590
  - FINP - Last successful CHECKDB: 2017-04-23 22:01:19.133
  - GridVis_EnMs - Last successful CHECKDB: 2017-05-18 22:10:48.120
  - master - Last successful CHECKDB:  never.
  - model
  - msdb
  - PROD77 - Last successful CHECKDB: 2016-02-23 21:33:24.343

**Priority 10: Performance**:

- Query Store Disabled - The new SQL Server 2016 Query Store feature has not been enabled on this database.

  - babtec_prod
  - D3PR
  - DEMO77
  - FINP
  - GridVis_EnMs

**Priority 50: DBCC Events**:

- DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS  - The user schorsch has run DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS 1 times between Sep 21 2017 11:57AM and Sep 21 2017 11:57AM. If this is a production box, know that you're clearing all data out of memory when this happens. What kind of monster would do that?
- DBCC SHRINK%  - The user schorsch has run file shrinks 6 times between Sep 21 2017 11:51PM and Okt  4 2017  9:02AM. So, uh, are they trying to fix corruption, or cause corruption?
- Overall Events  - 287 DBCC events have taken place between Sep 19 2017  1:40PM and Okt  4 2017  3:20PM. This does not include CHECKDB and other usually benign DBCC events.

**Priority 50: Performance**:

- File Growths Slow PROD77 - 2 growths took more than 15 seconds each. Consider setting file autogrowth to a smaller increment.

**Priority 50: Reliability**:

- Page Verification Not Optimal babtec_prod - Database [babtec_prod] has TORN_PAGE_DETECTION for page verification.  SQL Server may have a harder time recognizing and recovering from storage corruption.  Consider using CHECKSUM instead.

**Priority 100: Performance**:

- Many Plans for One Query  - 3576 plans are present for a single query in the plan cache - meaning we probably have parameterization issues.

**Priority 110: Performance**:

- Active Tables Without Clustered Indexes

  - babtec_prod - The [babtec_prod] database has heaps - tables without a clustered index - that are being actively queried.
  - D3PR - The [D3PR] database has heaps - tables without a clustered index - that are being actively queried.
  - DEMO77 - The [DEMO77] database has heaps - tables without a clustered index - that are being actively queried.
  - FINP - The [FINP] database has heaps - tables without a clustered index - that are being actively queried.
  - GridVis_EnMs - The [GridVis_EnMs] database has heaps - tables without a clustered index - that are being actively queried.
  - PROD77 - The [PROD77] database has heaps - tables without a clustered index - that are being actively queried.

**Priority 150: Performance**:

- Foreign Keys Not Trusted

  - babtec_prod - The [babtec_prod] database has foreign keys that were probably disabled, data was changed, and then the key was enabled again.  Simply enabling the key is not enough for the optimizer to use this key - we have to alter the table using the WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT parameter.
  - D3PR - The [D3PR] database has foreign keys that were probably disabled, data was changed, and then the key was enabled again.  Simply enabling the key is not enough for the optimizer to use this key - we have to alter the table using the WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT parameter.
- Inactive Tables Without Clustered Indexes

  - D3PR - The [D3PR] database has heaps - tables without a clustered index - that have not been queried since the last restart.  These may be backup tables carelessly left behind.
  - GridVis_EnMs - The [GridVis_EnMs] database has heaps - tables without a clustered index - that have not been queried since the last restart.  These may be backup tables carelessly left behind.
- Triggers on Tables babtec_prod - The [babtec_prod] database has 26 triggers.

**Priority 170: File Configuration**:

- System Database on C Drive

  - master - The master database has a file on the C drive.  Putting system databases on the C drive runs the risk of crashing the server when it runs out of space.
  - model - The model database has a file on the C drive.  Putting system databases on the C drive runs the risk of crashing the server when it runs out of space.
  - msdb - The msdb database has a file on the C drive.  Putting system databases on the C drive runs the risk of crashing the server when it runs out of space.

**Priority 170: Reliability**:

- Max File Size Set

  - D3PR - The [D3PR] database file d3_data_01 has a max file size set to 61440MB. If it runs out of space, the database will stop working even though there may be drive space available.
  - D3PR - The [D3PR] database file d3_data_idx_01 has a max file size set to 61440MB. If it runs out of space, the database will stop working even though there may be drive space available.
  - D3PR - The [D3PR] database file d3_firm_01 has a max file size set to 61440MB. If it runs out of space, the database will stop working even though there may be drive space available.
  - D3PR - The [D3PR] database file d3_firm_idx_01 has a max file size set to 61440MB. If it runs out of space, the database will stop working even though there may be drive space available.
  - D3PR - The [D3PR] database file d3_log_01 has a max file size set to 61440MB. If it runs out of space, the database will stop working even though there may be drive space available.
  - D3PR - The [D3PR] database file d3_phys_01 has a max file size set to 61440MB. If it runs out of space, the database will stop working even though there may be drive space available.
  - D3PR - The [D3PR] database file d3_phys_idx_01 has a max file size set to 61440MB. If it runs out of space, the database will stop working even though there may be drive space available.
  - D3PR - The [D3PR] database file d3_sys_01 has a max file size set to 20480MB. If it runs out of space, the database will stop working even though there may be drive space available.
  - D3PR - The [D3PR] database file d3_usr_01 has a max file size set to 20480MB. If it runs out of space, the database will stop working even though there may be drive space available.
  - D3PR - The [D3PR] database file d3_wort_01 has a max file size set to 20480MB. If it runs out of space, the database will stop working even though there may be drive space available.
  - D3PR - The [D3PR] database file d3_wort_idx_01 has a max file size set to 20480MB. If it runs out of space, the database will stop working even though there may be drive space available.

**Priority 200: Informational**:

- Backup Compression Default Off  - Uncompressed full backups have happened recently, and backup compression is not turned on at the server level. Backup compression is included with SQL Server 2008R2 & newer, even in Standard Edition. We recommend turning backup compression on by default so that ad-hoc backups will get compressed.
- Collation is Latin1_General_CS_AS FINP - Collation differences between user databases and tempdb can cause conflicts especially when comparing string values
- Collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS - Collation differences between user databases and tempdb can cause conflicts especially when comparing string values

  - DEMO77
  - PROD77
- Linked Server Configured  - BWIN2\INFOR is configured as a linked server. Check its security configuration as it is connecting with sa, because any user who queries it will get admin-level permissions.

**Priority 200: Monitoring**:

- Agent Jobs Without Failure Emails

  - The job syspolicy_purge_history has not been set up to notify an operator if it fails.
  - The job upd_durchpreis_monatl has not been set up to notify an operator if it fails.
  - The job upd_fertmengen_woche has not been set up to notify an operator if it fails.
  - The job upd_liegezeit_monatl has not been set up to notify an operator if it fails.
  - The job upd_vertreter_diff has not been set up to notify an operator if it fails.
  - The job UPDATE_CONNECT_IK has not been set up to notify an operator if it fails.
  - The job Wartung.Cleanup has not been set up to notify an operator if it fails.
  - The job Wartung.DBCC Check DB has not been set up to notify an operator if it fails.
  - The job Wartung.Index neu erstellen has not been set up to notify an operator if it fails.
  - The job Wartung.Statistiken aktualisieren has not been set up to notify an operator if it fails.
  - The job Wartung.Transactionlog Backup has not been set up to notify an operator if it fails.
  - The job Wartung.Vollbackup SystemDB has not been set up to notify an operator if it fails.
  - The job Wartung.Vollbackup UserDB has not been set up to notify an operator if it fails.
- No Alerts for Corruption  - SQL Server Agent alerts do not exist for errors 823, 824, and 825.  These three errors can give you notification about early hardware failure. Enabling them can prevent you a lot of heartbreak.
- No Alerts for Sev 19-25  - SQL Server Agent alerts do not exist for severity levels 19 through 25.  These are some very severe SQL Server errors. Knowing that these are happening may let you recover from errors faster.
- Not All Alerts Configured  - Not all SQL Server Agent alerts have been configured.  This is a free, easy way to get notified of corruption, job failures, or major outages even before monitoring systems pick it up.

**Priority 200: Non-Default Server Config**:

- Agent XPs  - This sp_configure option has been changed.  Its default value is 0 and it has been set to 1.
- Database Mail XPs  - This sp_configure option has been changed.  Its default value is 0 and it has been set to 1.
- default full-text language  - This sp_configure option has been changed.  Its default value is 1033 and it has been set to 1031.
- default language  - This sp_configure option has been changed.  Its default value is 0 and it has been set to 1.
- filestream access level  - This sp_configure option has been changed.  Its default value is 0 and it has been set to 1.
- max degree of parallelism  - This sp_configure option has been changed.  Its default value is 0 and it has been set to 4.
- max server memory (MB)  - This sp_configure option has been changed.  Its default value is 2147483647 and it has been set to 115000.
- min server memory (MB)  - This sp_configure option has been changed.  Its default value is 0 and it has been set to 10000.
- remote admin connections  - This sp_configure option has been changed.  Its default value is 0 and it has been set to 1.

**Priority 200: Performance**:

- cost threshold for parallelism  - Set to 5, its default value. Changing this sp_configure setting may reduce CXPACKET waits.
- Snapshot Backups Occurring  - 9 snapshot-looking backups have occurred in the last two weeks, indicating that IO may be freezing up.

**Priority 210: Non-Default Database Config**:

- Read Committed Snapshot Isolation Enabled - This database setting is not the default.

  - D3PR
  - FINP
- Recursive Triggers Enabled - This database setting is not the default.

  - DEMO77
  - PROD77
- Snapshot Isolation Enabled FINP - This database setting is not the default.

**Priority 240: Wait Stats**:

- 1 - ASYNC_NETWORK_IO  - 225.9 hours of waits, 143.5 minutes average wait time per hour, 0.2% signal wait, 2146022 waiting tasks, 378.9 ms average wait time.
- 2 - CXPACKET  - 43.1 hours of waits, 27.4 minutes average wait time per hour, 1.5% signal wait, 32608391 waiting tasks, 4.8 ms average wait time.

**Priority 250: Informational**:

- SQL Server is running under an NT Service account

  - I'm running as NT Service\MSSQL$INFOR. I wish I had an Active Directory service account instead.
  - I'm running as NT Service\SQLAgent$INFOR. I wish I had an Active Directory service account instead.

**Priority 250: Server Info**:

- Default Trace Contents  - The default trace holds 760 hours of data between Sep  3 2017  8:34PM and Okt  5 2017 12:50PM. The default trace files are located in: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.INFOR\MSSQL\Log
- Drive C Space  - 21308.00MB free on C drive
- Drive D Space  - 280008.00MB free on D drive
- Drive E Space  - 281618.00MB free on E drive
- Drive F Space  - 60193.00MB free on F drive
- Hardware  - Logical processors: 4. Physical memory: 128GB.
- Hardware - NUMA Config  - Node: 0 State: ONLINE Online schedulers: 4 Offline schedulers: 0 Processor Group: 0 Memory node: 0 Memory VAS Reserved GB: 281
- Server Last Restart  - Okt  1 2017  2:21PM
- Server Name  - BWINPDB\INFOR
- Services

  - Service: SQL Server (INFOR) runs under service account NT Service\MSSQL$INFOR. Last startup time: Okt  1 2017  2:22PM. Startup type: Automatic, currently Running.
  - Service: SQL Server-Agent (INFOR) runs under service account NT Service\SQLAgent$INFOR. Last startup time: not shown.. Startup type: Automatic, currently Running.
- SQL Server Last Restart  - Okt  1 2017  2:22PM
- SQL Server Service  - Version: 13.0.4001.0. Patch Level: SP1. Edition: Standard Edition (64-bit). AlwaysOn Enabled: 0. AlwaysOn Mgr Status: 2
- Virtual Server  - Type: (HYPERVISOR)
- Windows Version  - You're running a pretty modern version of Windows: Server 2012R2 era, version 6.3

**Priority 254: Rundate**:

- Captain's log: stardate something and something...

**EDIT:**

I'v already studied that best practices guide regarding setting up sql server with vmware , and we've set most of it according to this paper. Though, hyperthreading is not activated and NUMA isn't active on the vmware host. SQL Server is set to NUMA though.

**EDIT:**

I've issued the RECONFIGURE after setting the thresold for parallelism to 50, also my MAXDOP setting of wasn't configured.

I also checked with our vmware admin, seems like I was misinformed. Our CPUs are set to 2.6GHz not 4.6 GHz. I've corrected that information above.

**EDIT:**

We tried to set some network related according to this [vmwarekb](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2129176) and [guide](https://hm-incloud.com/vmxnet3-boost-server-2012r2/). We also added 4 more cores to the VM. CPU usage stayed the same.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the background info. Start by running sp_Blitz as described here and pasting it into your question: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/

Comment: @BrentOzar, I added the result of sp_blitz to my post

Comment: OK, bad news: the answer is still the same as the last one you got. ASYNC_NETWORK_IO means that the SQL Server has finished processing the query results, and it's waiting on the machine on the other end of the pipe to digest the results. See the original answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/186602/426

Comment: @Emptyslot, make sure SQL Server on VMWare best practices are followed: https://www.vmware.com/content/dam/digitalmarketing/vmware/en/pdf/solutions/sql-server-on-vmware-best-practices-guide.pdf.

Comment: Can you check if power plan is set to high performance and not the default (balanced). I have seen many issues due to it being default.

Comment: @Kin, setting the power plan to high performance was the 'solution' to my last question regarding ASYNC_NETWORK_IO. It helped during testing phase, but ASYNC_NETWORK_IO is back.

I'v already studied that best practices guide, and we've set most of it accorind to this paper. Though, hyperthreading is not activated and NUMA isn't active on the vmware host. SQL Server is set to NUMA though.

Comment: @Emptyslot Your CPU is 4.6GHz and VM is reporting 2.6 .. so there must be something at host level which is throttling. Also, can you check why 700+ threads are spawned ? Probably most of your queries are going parallel - adjust cost threshold of parallelism e.g. start with 35 and adjust it. That should help you.

Comment: You said you changed MAXDOP, but I don't see it in the sp_configure results. It appears it hasn't taken effect. Run RECONFIGURE for it to take effect. But first, also change "max server memory" to 129772 (based on your 128GB of RAM) and "cost threshold for parallelism" to 50. Then run RECONFIGURE for all of them to take effect. But that ASYNC_NETWORK_IO is still your biggest problem and goes back to my last answer.

Comment: @TaraKizer, wouldn't I bottleneck my OS when I set the Max Memory to the max available memory of the VM?

You are right, though, I forgot to issue the RECONFIGURE command after setting MAXDOP. Also wouldn't increasing the parallelism cost thresold to 50 result in much more singe threaded CPU usage? I'm gonna do it anyway, but am just curious

Comment: @TaraKizer, I've change the settings accordingly, CPU usage is still high.

Comment: Yeah I didn't expect CPU utilization to drop by changing those settings, just wanted your server to not be using the default, not recommended settings. Regarding the threshold change, it just means less queries will go parallel as they now need to have higher cost before going parallel. And regarding the memory question, 129772 is NOT 128GB of RAM. I gave 12.8GB of RAM back to the OS and came to 129772. Your default setting meant to use all available memory.

Comment: Have you determined what queries are causing that CPU usage? Wait stats are not necessarily the right tool because busy CPUs do *not* wait at the moment. I'd simply execute sp_whoisactive by Adam Machanic 10 times and get a sample of expensive queries running.

Comment: Some of the others commenting here are hardcore SQL tuning consultants, so feel free to ignore this, but I've never liked assigning that high a percentage of my servers' RAM to one application.  I have always perceived Windows to start aggressively paging to disk when the OS thinks RAM is ~80% utilised.  Pre-allocating that RAM in SQL Server means the OS sees it as utilised.  If you are fully-SSD you might not notice this but, if not, I might try targeting 50-65%, depending on what else runs on that server.  If you have 128GB dedicated to your VM, the most I'd probably allocate to SQL is 80GB.

Comment: Based on the network I/O suspicion, have you disabled all of the network adapter driver offloading features?  I've not heard of this being a problem on VMware, but it's easy to try.  A simple throughput test of copying a large file between servers will tell you whether it's a problem, and if disabling the features fixes it.

Comment: @TonyHinkle, yeah. We did that yesterdays evening according to this guid an vmware kb. https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2129176    https://hm-incloud.com/vmxnet3-boost-server-2012r2/

Comment: Looks like there's an expensive query running from management studio and the stats update also looks very expensive. Run sp_whoisactive a few times more from time to time to see if these are just rare anomalies or maybe running all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To anwer my own question. ASYNC_NETWORK_IO actually wasn't the real problem. We fixed our performance problem by following this guide for latency sensitive workloads:

[Best Practices for Performance Tuning of Latency-Sensitive Workloads in vSphere VMs](https://www.vmware.com/content/dam/digitalmarketing/vmware/en/pdf/techpaper/vmw-tuning-latency-sensitive-workloads-white-paper.pdf)

I marked the settings we applied to our system with yellow color here:

[image]

I think the settings with the most impact were the **numa configuration** and setting **latency sensitivity** to **high**. Which both required to explicity allocate/reserve physical CPU cores and RAM for the VM.

We also added more cores to the VM an now need to upgrade our SQL Server licence from Standard to Enterprise.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer details. We are running SQL in Vsphere as well and may need to review these options should issues occur. Please keep this answer up. Sorry that someone -1ed you. +1

Comment: DidmOu tune these only for the SQL Server or also/only for the application as well?

Comment: We also tuned the app server with that setting. We are also considering to tune our virtual desktops with the latency setting to middle/normal. My guess is that this would resolve our problems regarding async_network_io

Answer (score 18):

As discussed [the last time you asked this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186597/strange-performance-problem-with-sql-server-2016/), your top wait is ASYNC_NETWORK_IO. SQL Server is sitting around waiting for the machine on the other end of the pipe to digest the next row of query results.

I got this info from the waits stats results of sp_Blitz (thanks for pasting that in):

> 1 - ASYNC_NETWORK_IO - 225.9 hours of waits, 143.5 minutes average
>   wait time per hour, 0.2% signal wait, 2146022 waiting tasks, 378.9 ms
>   average wait time.

Don't go off troubleshooting CPU threads - that's not related. Focus on your primary wait type and things that would cause that wait type.

To troubleshoot this further, run [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/) or [sp_BlitzFirst](https://www.brentozar.com/askbrent/) (disclaimer: I'm one of the authors of that) - both of which will list the queries that are running currently. Look at the wait info column, find the queries waiting for ASYNC_NETWORK_IO, and look at the apps & servers they're running from.

From there, you can try:

- Checking to see if those app servers are underpowered (like if they're maxed out on CPU, or paging to disk) and tune them
- Working with the app developers to see if they're doing row-by-row processing on the results (like for every row that comes back from SQL Server, the app goes off and does some processing before asking for the next row of results)
- Working with the app developers to select less data (like less rows or less columns if they don't need all the data - sometimes you see this when folks accidentally do a SELECT * and bring back more data than they needed, or they ask for all the rows when they only really need the top 1000)

**Update with sp_WhoIsActive** - in the sp_WhoIsActive screenshot you posted, you've got a couple of queries that are waiting on ASYNC_NETWORK_IO. For those, refer to the above instructions.

In the remainder of the queries, look at the "status" column of sp_WhoIsActive - the majority of them are "sleeping." That means they're not working at all - they're waiting for the apps on the other end of the pipe to send their next command. They have transactions open (see the "open_tran_count" column) but there's nothing SQL Server can do to speed up a sleeping transaction. These queries have been open for over forty minutes (the first column in sp_WhoIsActive. *They're just not doing anything anymore.* You've gotta get those folks to commit their transactions and close their connections. This isn't a performance tuning issue.

Everything we're seeing here points to a scenario where we're waiting on the app.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. We've checked the app servers, they are not underpowered. We are checking your other points. There are a lot of statements that that do something like SELECT alias.* FROM table alias WHERE alias.clumn = value AND CreateDate >= SomeDate.  Which isn't pretty, but those are the same SQL Statements that ran 'smoothly' with the last version of our ERP system (Infor COM 7.1) and with oracle 9g. Why would the run worse with the MS SQL Server and Infor COM 7.1. There are no statements that are standing our in any way. Our erp consultant checks all that I send him.

Comment: OK, you need to start with the section marked "To troubleshoot this further" - that's the next steps. I can't make that any more clear. Thanks!

Comment: That is what I'm doing. I'm sending the queries the two procedures show to our consultant.

Comment: @Emptyslot well, you know how it is, can't trust those consultants. ;-)

Comment: As I understand it the CPU usage has increased dramatically and he's after the reason for that. I don't believe anything triggering high ASYNC_NETWORK_IO waits can cause such CPU consumption.

Comment: That's true. If I talk about wait stats, everybody just stares at me like I can't be right with what I'm saying. Because nobody knows what wait stats are or mean. Despite me explaining it like a thousand times. Maybe I should just give up and quit.

Comment: CPU use isn’t making the queries slower, though, that’s the catch. The “high” CPU may just be that other guests are using more CPU, so the percentages look higher for the same amount of activity. You can wax your car’s bumper, but if you’re on square wheels, that’s the bottleneck. Wait stats tell you what the real bottleneck is so you don’t waste time waxing bumpers.

Comment: We just restarted the server, gave it 4 more CPUs and also applied some commands for the VMx3network adapter. This did no result in any improvement.  There are no other guests that could bottleneck our sql VM. We checked that. Whats really strange is, that ASYNC_NETWORK_IO appears over all databases for all applications, not just the ERP system, but also the quality insurance software, the document archiving software etc. All of them.

Comment: Also there is another thing. If I open up the SSMS and conncet to the sql server instance with a SQL User login that has highly restricted right, It takes at least 10 seconds to load the list of databases / objects of the sql server. Seems like its checking some privileges and stuff like that. But why would it take that long? (I'm the only one connected to the sql server right now)

Comment: @Emptyslot - this will be the last time I reply unless you put in the stuff that I've asked for three times now: run sp_WhoIsActive or sp_BlitzFirst (disclaimer: I'm one of the authors of that) - both of which will list the queries that are running currently. That will also include your SSMS connection, and show what it's waiting on. Please understand that I'm volunteering my time here to help you, and I've been polite, but the politeness stops here: DO THE THING I'VE ASKED YOU TO DO THREE TIMES.

Comment: I didn't read your suggestion as: 'post the result here on stack exchange'. I now posted the results above.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Windows is reporting the clock speed of your apprently 4.6Ghz CPU cores as 2.6Ghz... I would run a tool like CPU-Z to check what speed they are actually running at, and then look at changing the power settings in both Windows and the BIOS/Management OS to disable any power saving settings that may be throttling the cores to a lower speed.

Comment: I was misinformed, the CPU Cores were at 2.6 GHz all the time. There are no power saving setting active, neither on the host nor on the guest.

Comment: I would look more closely into the 'Active Tables Without Clustered Indexes' warning. If you have large heaps that are actively being queried that will kill performance badly...

Comment: Unfortunatly there was only one table that has no Clustered index. It has two columns, one of which is NVARCHAR the other is of datatype IMAGE.  It already had a nonclustered unique index for the first column, I added a clustered index as well. But that didn't help much.